# Fruit disappears sometimes Snake in C

Tags: c

Im making a snake game in c, most things seem to be working right but I found a bug that I can't seem to fix. The fruit in my game sometimes just disappears for no reason. First, I thought that the problem was that I was generating it outside of the play-area but I put a restriction on that and the problem still exists.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int gameOver = 0, width = 20, height = 20, x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score;
int s;
int totalTail;
int tailX[100], tailY[100];

void Setup() {
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    x = height / 2;
    y = width / 2;
    score = 0;

    do {
        fruitX = rand() % height;
        fruitY = rand() % width;
    } while (fruitX <= 0 || fruitY <= 0 || fruitX == x || fruitY == y || fruitX > height || fruitY > width);
}

void Draw() {
    system("cls");

    for (int i = 0; i < height;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == width - 1 || j == height - 1) {
                printf("#");
            }
            else if (i == x && j == y) { //generates head
                printf("O");
            }
            else if (fruitX == i && fruitY == j) { //generates fruit
                printf("F");
            }
            else {
                int print = 0; //generates tail
                for (int k = 0; k < totalTail; k++) {
                    if (tailX[k] == i && tailY[k] == j) {
                        printf("o");
                        print = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (print == 0) {
                    printf(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Score: %d", score); //displays score

}
void Input() {

    if (_kbhit()) {
        switch (_getch()) {
        case 'w':
            s = 1;
            break;
        case 's':
            s = 2;
            break;
        case 'a':
            s = 3;
            break;
        case 'd':
            s = 4;
            break;
        case 'x':
            gameOver = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Logic() {
    int prevX = tailX[0];
    int prevY = tailY[0];
    int prev2X, prev2Y;
    tailX[0] = x;
    tailY[0] = y;
    for (int i = 1; i < totalTail; i++)
    {
        prev2X = tailX[i];
        prev2Y = tailY[i];
        tailX[i] = prevX;
        tailY[i] = prevY;
        prevX = prev2X;
        prevY = prev2Y;
    }

    switch (s) {
    case 1:
        x--;
        break;
    case 2:
        x++;
        break;
    case 3:
        y--;
        break;
    case 4:
        y++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < totalTail; i++) { //checks if the head and tail have collided
        if (tailX[i] == x && tailY[i] == y) {
            gameOver = 1;
        }
    }

    if (x > 18 || y > 18 || x <= 0 || y <= 0) { //checks if player is out of the area
        gameOver = 1;
    }

    if (x == fruitX && y == fruitY) { // adds point to score and regenerates fruit, I think the problem is here, not sure though
        score += 1;
        totalTail++;
        do {
            fruitX = rand() % height;
            fruitY = rand() % width;
        } while (fruitX <= 0 || fruitY <= 0 || fruitX == x || fruitY == y || fruitX > height || fruitY > width);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Setup();

    while (gameOver != 1) {
        Input();
        Logic();
        Draw();
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are the points with `x=height` and `y=width` supposed to be visible? BTW, there is no point to regenerate *both* coordinates when only one is not satisfying conditions

Comment: Use a debugger, and let the game run until the fruit disappears, then stop the execution and look at the values for `fruitX` and `fruitY`.

Comment: ...or print these coordinates always in the corner somewhere

Comment: `int totalTail;` -- what value does it have? (especially when you use it as your loop limits)

Comment: The fruit can still be on the edges. You need to change the check in `Setup` a bit to not match where you print `'#'`

Comment: By default ``totalTail`` should have 0. Im so stupid, the problem was that it was spawning in the edges, I cant believe I didnt see that.

Comment: That game is a total falacy, snakes clearly don't eat fruit.